# How can Safari on iPhone automatically close a played video

Tags: iphone, html, video, safari

How do you get safari on iphone to automatically close a video and return to web page?

I guess it is some javascript but cant figure out what - I would probably use

```
myVideo.addEventListener('ended',handleEvent,false);
```

But not too sure what to do once the event is fired

Comment: An answer is documented in detail [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438520/html5-video-player-behavior-on-iphone-and-ipod-in-safari-web-apps).

Answer (score 5):

Someone has asked the same question before, and please check it here:
[Closing iPhone Video Player using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175765/closing-iphone-video-player-using-javascript)

jQuery -

```
$('video').get(0).webkitExitFullScreen();
```

Uncertain what iOS version this was supported.

Hope above helps!